# linux setfacl permission to different user and able to write in recursive

Tags: permissions, mask

I have tow user in same group
1. user 1 : datauser
2. user 2 : webuser
3. Group  : apache

What set permission using setfact to either of user can create directory/file recursive.

Ex.:
    directory /web/foo/
    What permission/mask set (using setfact), so that datauser/webuser can create directory under foo dir (recursive).

```
#datauser : mkdir -p /web/foo/datadir/
#webuser : mkdir -p /web/foo/datadir/webdir
#datauser : touch /web/foo/datadir/webdir/datafile.txt
#webuser : touch /web/foo/datadir/webfile.txt
etc...

I try with below command, but when any directory created using      
webuser:apache, then datauser:apache not able to write under that.

setfacl -Rm u:webuser:rwX,d:u:webuser:rwX foo
setfacl -Rm u:datauser:rwX,d:u:datauser:rwX foo
setfacl -Rm m:rwX,d:m:rwX foo
```

---

That umask and chmod not work.
[datauser]$ mkdir foo
[datauser]$ chmod g+ws foo
[datauser]$ umask 002 foo

[datauser]$ getfacl foo
 file: foo
 owner: datauser 
 group: apache
 flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x

Now create directory using webuser:apache user [PHP : mkdir(/web/foo/browser, 0755, ture); ]
And directory permission is:
[datauser]$ getfacl foo/browser/
 file: foo/browser/
 owner: apache
 group: apache
 flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

Now create file under browser dir. getting permission denied.

[datauser]$ touch foo/browser/command.txt
touch: cannot touch ‘foo/browser/command.txt’: Permission denied

Answer (score 1):

How about using `chmod g+ws /web/foo`? This sets the `setgid` and `write` bits on the directory, which makes all created files' groups to be `apache` in that directory, and allows all `apache` group users to write to that directory and create further directories inside it.

And another thing that you need to do is to update your `umask` so that group has write permissions by default. So, you should add `umask 002` somewhere in your startup files so that group gets write permissions by default.

Comment: In that newly created directory not able to write...
dir created using webuser /web/foo/webdir/, datauser not able to create dir under webdir.

Comment: I updated the answer, you also need to add `write` bit for the group.

Comment: Another updated, added `umask`

Comment: That also not work... update in main question.

Comment: `umask` has to be set in every shell session startup, that is, add `umask 002` command somewhere in your shell startup scripts. The problem in your attempt is that the second shell session has the standard `022` umask, which means group doesn't get write permission.